# How to get text from edittext of inflated LinerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, layout-inflater

I have a `LinearLayout` (say parent) in whcih i'm inflating another `LinearLayout` (say child) which contains an `EditText` & `ImageButton`.

I am inflating child layout on click of a button in main layout. When one clicks on `ImageButton` of child layout that layout is gets removed. I have setup this with no problem.

Now I want to get text of all the `EditText` of child layout,when one click Save button of `ActionBar`.

Following is the method that I'm using to inflate my view. And `mainLayout` is my parent layout. Now how can I get text of all added `EditText` anywhere in my activity ?

```
private void addEditView(final LinearLayout mainLayout) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_phone_number_listview, null);

    //Get the EditText in you xml to set the new id 
    EditText editText = (EditText) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.et_pn);
    editText.setId(4000+1);//mainLayout.getChildCount()

    ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove_raw);
    remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mainLayout.removeView((View)v.getParent());
        }
    });  
    //add the view into the LinearLayout (global variable)        
    mainLayout.addView(theInflatedView);
}
```

**What have I tried :**

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.phone_info);

            int count = ll.getChildCount();
            for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
            {
                Log.e("child count:", "count:" + count + "ID:" + ll.getChildAt(i).getId());
                View vi = ll.getChildAt(i);
                if(vi instanceof EditText)
                {
                    // you got the spinner
                    EditText s = (EditText) findViewById(4000+i);
                    Log.e("Item selected",s.getText().toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try String text = editText.getText().toString();

Comment: what is the need for `setId`?

Comment: @Raghunandan :I will remove it if not required. i just want text of eddittext. that ID doesn't matter for now

Comment: @I-droid declare this `EditText editText` as an instance variable. Intialize EditText as `editText = (EditText) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.et_pn);` then `editText.getText().toString()`

Comment: @Raghunandan: will this work when i have more one `EditText` ???

Answer (score 0):

On your parent  `mainLayout` use the `findViewById()` method to find your child Linear Layout. Than on it find its child elements with the same logic. Every view has the `findViewById()` method for its childs.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
ArrayList<String> edittextValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    View view = (View)mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_pn);
    edittextValues.add(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: getting `nullPointerException` at last line. Means edittext is not getting there.

Comment: still getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here IMO is that instead to use a `ListView` you try to create your own list appending each `View`.

My proposed solution:
Use a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`. You will be able to access `EditText` and `ImageButton` for each row inside your `ArrayAdapter`.

**Edit**
Following our discussion and the problem being that user inputed text is not saved and lost after adding rows due to the recycling property of `ListView`, you should customize your `ArrayAdapter` to save the text typed by the user.
This can be done in the `getView` of your `ArrayAdapter` as explained here:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441210/891479.

Comment: I had already tried this approach. But in that case I was unable to retain values of previous `EditText` when i add new item. If have working example then i can use it again.

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but you should be able to access all the values of the Object List given in the ArrayAdapter constructor ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects). you can also customize ArrayAdapter to match your data model.

Comment: When I add new item into to ArrayAdapter, the values which user have already entered should be retained in view. But when I was updating view with adapter those text of `EditText` was got cleared.

Comment: I think it is link to the ListView recycling, other problem bu the cause and solution could be the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438676/edittext-in-listview-without-it-recycling-input. Basically what you need to do is save the input for your EditTexts in some data structure/Object list or array.